# Which is preferred : Nested If's or Exit Sub / Function?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Recently I've been working on legacy vb.net code and during code peer review it was recommended not to use Exit Sub / Function but instead to nest all functionality in IF statements.

When I initially started developing I used to do it this way instinctively (Nest the IF's), not only did it seem more logical, it just seemed less confusing.

However at some point I worked with a team that treated nested IF's as "evil", and so Exit subs / functions I was told was preferred. I'm pretty sure they produced some MS best practice material to back this up.

So this question is for experienced developers, which way is truly preferred? If you give an answer could you also please state your sources, or just mention that this is a preference preferred by your team / company / personal and give reasons.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT as requested: Code Samples

Exit Sub :

```
Private Sub DoSomeWork()
 if not conditionMetFromAnotherFunction() then
      exit Sub 
 end if

 'Method work starts here
End Sub
```

Nested IFs:

```
Private Sub DoSomeWork()
 if conditionMetFromAnotherFunction() then
     'Method work starts here
 end if
End Sub
```

Comment: as long as you don't use goto's... :P

Comment: Can you show examples of each version?  Based on description alone, I'd always vote against nested conditionals.  If it's another level of abstraction, it should go to another function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David pointed out in his comment, nested if statements can add to the complexity of your code.

Imagine the following (simplified) code :

```
Private Sub DoSomeWork()
    if conditionMetFromAnotherFunction() then
        if conditionDependantUponPreviousCondition then
            ' Do the work
        end if
    end if
End Sub
```

Or the following

```
Private Sub DoSomeWork()
    if not conditionMetFromAnotherFunction()
        return
    else if not conditionDependantUponPreviousCondition 
        return
    end if


    ' If we're here, everything's all good
    ' Do the work...
End Sub
```

If your conditions get more complex, returning makes it much more easy to understand that under some conditions, your code is not doing anything, and makes your code more readable.

Otherwise, you have to read all the function and mentally parse the nested if's to see that nothing's done.

Comment: The big argument i could make here is that now you can't tell whether `someOtherCondition` depends on `conditionMetFromAnotherFunction()`.  Logically, if it doesn't, i could switch those two conditions and prevent having to check a potentially costly `conditionMetFromAnotherFunction()` by filtering with a much simpler and faster `someOtherCondition` first.  But if it does, then switching them will break.

Comment: I guess you are right, but I was only trying to show that it makes code more readable. In production code, of course, if someCondition depended on conditionMetFromAnotherFunction(), I'd use AndAlso to show the dependency between the two. And if it did get more complex, you'd have to refactor to another function anyways :)

Answer (score 22):

If you don't exit your functions early, you will reach a point where your code looks like this:

[image: stumble on code]

No one can tell me this is a better style than returning early from a function.

Comment: Is that the falling figure from the original Myst?  Awesome.

Comment: I used to call code like this Star wars code - one dev I knew had a 4000 line function with 16 to 20 nested levels of IF and other statements. Zoom out of the code, I just saw lots of star destroyers heading for the attack! Oh and VS 2010 could not debug all the way into the function.

Answer (score 6):

> during code peer review it was recommended not to use Exit Sub / Function but instead to nest all functionality in IF statements.

This is horrible advice. It’s as simple as that. Ignore it. In fact, the opposite is usually true, especially in situations where nested indentation would be required, or where you check your parameters for validity and might exit early: the code in your question is a good example of that. *Do* use early exit here.

There is no “official” source for that (what would be official?) but it’s pretty much consensus among good programmers, with a very small minority who opposes this. For more discussion about this see the [discussion on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/118703/2366).

However, I’d advise using `Return` instead of `Exit {Sub|Function}`.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, do you know of any official sources that I can lookup to check because now I am confused which is right or wrong or if it is subjective - thank you.

Comment: @JL it's totally subjective.  The reasons's I've basically heard is that single-exit gives you a good place to put a breakpoint to examine the value being returned, or the state of the object after the method is done.  Personally, I much prefer to not have 10 levels of nested IFs and accept that there's no single exit.

Comment: @Jonathan I object, strongly. It’s certainly *not* subjective, there are objective code complexity and quality measures which apply here. Heavily nested code objectively complicates understanding. Early exit on the other hand allows the reader of the code to distinguish at once which cases are or aren’t handled in a given method.

Answer (score 3):

As with anything, "it depends."  Either one can be distasteful if used in the wrong context.

For example, what is `conditionMetFromAnotherFunction()` checking?  If it's checking some kind of required pre-condition for `DoSomeWork()` then I'd even go so far as to through an exception instead of just quietly exiting the function.  `ArgumentException` would be useful if it was checking the validity of an argument passed to the function, for example.  Quietly exiting doesn't seem right if something in the system was actually wrong.

For the nested conditionals, that's **definitely** messy.  Keep in mind the rule of thumb that **a function should "do one thing."**  Checking that condition is one thing.  So in that case the `'Method work starts here` should be nothing more than a call to another method which actually does the work.  It should *not* be many lines of code all wrapped in one big conditional.  *And* the function names should accurately reflect what it is they're doing.  So this one would be `DoWorkIfConditional` (in the contrived example) and the other method would be `DoWork`.

It's OK for the functions to check pre-conditions before doing work.  If pre-conditions aren't met, I'd consider throwing an exception.  But that depends on the actual logic of the application which isn't really conveyed in this example.

Comment: The "do one thing" mentality can be carried *way* too far, though.  If, rather than nesting 10 levels of `If`s, one simply hid the nesting within 10 levels of function calls, it'd be even worse.  At least with the `If`s, all the relevant code is (somewhat) together...with the functions, i'd have to yoyo through the code for a while just to see what's eventually supposed to happen.

Comment: @cHao: Well, any well-intended approach can be made unmaintainable by a developer who doesn't know better :)  The point is that each function should perform a single task and those tasks should be arranged logically.  One function's "task" could be a long atomic process which involves stepping through many other functions.  That's fine.  As long as each discrete "step" is its own function.  Excessive nesting is bad no matter how it's done.  Logically organizing the code and re-factoring when needed is critical.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading the answers [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from) for a good roundup on this topic.

To summarize: *Single Entry / Single Exit* developed in languages where you can have multiple entry points to a function and you can also return **to** different positions in the code. It has been misinterpreted as allowing only one point in the code where you can return **from**.

The "best practice" to use only one return / exit statement in a subprogram comes from languages with explicit heap management, where the resources of a subprogram are freed at the end of the subprogram, so the control flow is required to pass through there. This is not applicable in languages that are based on .NET or JVM.

Overall, code is usually more readable when you are allowed to use multiple returns.

Answer (score 1):

IMO nested if's are a very quick rout to horrid spaghetti code.  Generally speaking if your deeply nesting you code then your trying to do to much work in your method and most likely will benefit from refactoring into smaller parts.

Having said that sometimes it cannot be avoided so there is no one answer fits all.